# How to enable CORS in nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

I got stuck that I don't know how to enable `CORS` in `nginx`? Honestly, I've found so many solution to enable `CORS` in nginx and one of them is https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html but I've added those code inside my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and restart `nginx` server. But I've tried inside postman again and following error raised by `nginx`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>405 Not Allowed</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>405 Not Allowed</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.12.1</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /var/www/test/app/;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default/*.conf;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

    location / {
    }
```

Comment: Please show your nginx.conf and your request

Comment: @AlexC I've edited my question.

Comment: You missed OPTIONS into allow methods.

Comment: @AlexC still not working

Comment: @ppshein, please show your request details

Comment: @AlexC pls try that url `http://sanmel.wave.money/#/callback`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in no way a secure solution... but this is what I have currently in my set up and it is working. Maybe you can modify it to your needs. Feel free everyone to tell me how wrong it is and maybe we can get a better solution for everyone.

```
location / {

      dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;

      # Preflighted requestis
      if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
        return 200;
      }

      # CORS WHITELIST EVERYTHING
      # This is allowing everything because I am running
      # locally so there should be no security issues.
      if ($request_method = (GET|POST|OPTIONS|HEAD|DELETE)) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
      }

       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```